# Max 3 results per group (shops and their prices)

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

I have to get from a table containing something like

```
ShopId  ArticleId  Price  ArticleName

  1        1a      2.00   Fahrrad
  1        1b      3.00   Fahrrad
  1        1c      4.00   Fahrrad
  1        1d      9.99   Fahrrad
  2        2a      2.00   Fahrrad
  2        2b      3.10   Fahrrad
  2        2c      3.50   Fahrrad
  2        2d      9.99   Fahrrad
```

max. 3 ArticleId's per ShopId ordered by min. Price as result, e.g.:

```
ShopId  ArticleId  Price  ArticleName

  1        1a      2.00   Fahrrad
  1        1b      3.00   Fahrrad
  1        1c      4.00   Fahrrad
  2        2a      2.00   Fahrrad
  2        2b      3.10   Fahrrad
  2        2c      3.50   Fahrrad
```

Can anyone please help?
So it's something like min(`Price`) and group by `ShopId` but with 3 results not 1.

Comment: Show us the syntax you have so far

Comment: There are some answers and useful links and discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a bash. Don't know the name of your table so I've called it `shopArticle`:

```
select t.ShopId,t.ArticleId,t.Price,t.ArticleName
from
(
select sa.*,
            CASE sa.ShopId 
            WHEN @curShopId
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curShopId := sa.ShopId END rank
from shopArticle sa
join (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curShopId := '') r
order by sa.ShopId,sa.Price asc
) t
where t.rank <=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the real column-names the result is in short form:
set @cr := 0, @cs := "";

select `s`.`ShopTitle`,`p`.*,
@cr := if(@cs = `p`.`ShopId`, @cr + 1, 1) as `cr`,
@cs := `p`.`ShopId` as `cs`

from `affili_products2` `p` force index(PRIMARY)
left join `affili_shops` `s` on `p`.`ShopId`=`s`.`ShopId`

where `p`.`Keywords` like "%hobby%"

group by `p`.`ShopId`, `p`.`Price`
having cr <= 3
order by `s`.`ShopTitle` asc,`p`.`Price` asc